# Creating a survey via the API with a Basic or Select account

Tags: api, surveymonkey

Under "Scopes" the API documentation says "...the Create/Modify Surveys scope is available to Free (Basic) plans", but later contradicts that in the table showing "Platinum/Enterprise" as the minimum plan for the Create/Modify Surveys scope.

I am developing an application for a client that I believe has a Platinum account.  However, I myself only have a Basic account and am reluctant to invest in a Platinum account for this small development project.

The client requires the creation a tool that generates surveys via the API, which seems pretty straightforward, except that I am unable to do so with my account. Is there some way my client can allow my account to access a development app on their account so I can test survey creation?  Or could I do so myself with a Basic or Select account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Create/Modify Surveys scope will be moved down to the SELECT plan. Also, we will be providing developers time-limited full access to all the endpoints (except feature endpoints like benchmarks which requires the user to have bought the benchmark) when accessing their own account.

This should be available within a week or two. Check back at your app and the docs at https://developer.surveymonkey.com/ soon to see when the changes have been released.

Let us know if you have any more questions!

Comment: Is there an estimated roll-out date yet?  I'm nearing a deadline and may need to use a different survey method if I can't develop against the SurveyMonkey API.